# Why the date_add function behaves differently with adding an interval in presto?

Tags: sql, presto

Why the `date_add` function behaves differently with adding an `interval`?

`SELECT date_trunc('month', parse_datetime(concat('2022-10-30 22:20:45', '+08:00'), 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ')) - INTERVAL '1' MONTH}`

`SELECT date_add('month',-1, date_trunc('month', parse_datetime(concat('2022-10-30 22:20:45', '+08:00'), 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ')))`

The first version gives me `2022-08-31 00:00:00.000 +08:00`
The second version gives me `2022-09-01 00:00:00.000 +08:00`

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, I suggest post it on presto github interval. Note that it reproduces for trino also. Also potentially it can be connected to daylight savings time change, cause for September is does not repro.

Comment: Submitted issue for [Trino](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/15103)